# Connect two tables together and sum the top three of a specific field on the second table to the first table

Tags: mysql

Here is the issue.  I have looke through these threads for a while now and have yet to find the exact solution.

I have two tables like most question this has to do with joining the two tables.  one is basicly a table with a list of runners little over 20,000 records currently the second table is a list of results for those runners it has alittle over 35000 records.  The second table is actualy a view that contains all the result info plus age grades and a Rating which are generated by the view.  What I need now is to combine the top three ratings per each runner.  I tried this First.

```
SELECT
  r.id, 
  r.FirstName,
  r.MiddleName,
  r.LastName,
  r.Age,
  r.Gender,
  r.City,
  r.State,
  ROUND((SELECT SUM(re.Rating) rating FROM vwResults re WHERE re.runnerid = r.id ORDER BY re.Rating DESC LIMIT 3)/3,2) Rating
FROM Runners r
```

Unfortunitly that failed What I'm trying to do is sum the top three ratings from the results table and then devide it be 3 to get the avrage.  this would be the avrage rating for that user.  I have tried several diffrent variations of the code above and I did get one to work partialy but it took 8 seconds to load 30 records and the data was incorrect.  Is there any way to do this so that I can create a new Runner view that has the rating built in?  I would prefer not to use a procedure if at all possible.

```
Runners Table Structure
id int(11)
FirstName varchar(50)
MiddleName varchar(50)
LastName varchar(50)
Age int(3)
Gender varchar(2)
City varchar(50)
State varchar(2)
userid int(11)

vwResults View Structure
DistanceID int(4)
distance varchar(100)
RaceID int(11)
name varchar(100)
FirstName varchar(50)
LastName varchar(50)
place int(100)
Gender varchar(2)
age int(11)
finistime varchar(100)
pace time
agegrade varbinary(19)
ResultID int(11)
RunnerID int(11)
typeid int(11)
ftimesec bigint(10)
Rating decimal(18,2)
```

The only thing I needd from vwResults is the top three ratings sumed and / 3 to get a new avrage rating and all the info in the Runners table.

I am trying to create a function that will get the ratings but I know nothing about mysql functions could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here

```
      CREATE FUNCTION GetRating(
      Runnerid int( 11) 
      )
      RETURNS decimal( 18, 2) 
      READS SQL DATA
      BEGIN
      DECLARE Rat decimal(18,2);
      SELECT  ROUND(SUM(Rating)/3,2) INTO Rat  FROM vwResults WHERE runnerid = Runnerid GROUP BY runnerid
     ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 3;
     RETURN(Rat);
     END
```

I am trying to get the code below to work however there seems to be a problem with it keep getting the below error.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE usb_GetRatings() 
        BEGIN 
        SET @rank = NULL; 
        SET @prevrunnerid = NULL;  
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ttRunners;
        SELECT r.id, r.FirstName,r.MiddleName, 
        r.LastName,r.Age,r.Gender,r.City,r.State,  
        ROUND(top3rating.Rating, 2) as Rating  INTO ttRunners
        FROM Runners as r 
        JOIN (SELECT runnerid, AVG(Rating) as Rating 
          FROM (SELECT if(@prevrunnerid = runnerid, 
                      @rank := @rank + 1, 
                      @rank := 1) as rank, 
                   @prevrunnerid := runnerid 
                       as runnerid, 
                   Rating 
            FROM vwResults 
            ORDER BY runnerid, Rating) as sq 
         WHERE rank <= 3 
         GROUP BY runnerid) as top3rating 
        on (r.id = top3rating.runnerid); 
      END
```

Comment: added structure to the main post but it didn't put it in code view :S

Comment: Be sure you are modifying the delimiter like in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?  Put it in a procedure.

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE get_top3_rating_avg() AS BEGIN
    SET @rank = NULL;
    SET @prevrunnerid = NULL;
    SELECT r.id, r.FirstName,r.MiddleName,
           r.LastName,r.Age,r.Gender,r.City,r.State, 
           ROUND(top3rating.Rating, 2) as Rating 
    FROM Runners as r
    JOIN (SELECT runnerid, AVG(Rating) as Rating
          FROM (SELECT if(@prevrunnerid = runnerid,
                          @rank := @rank + 1,
                          @rank := 1) as rank,
                       @prevrunnerid := runnerid
                           as runnerid,
                       Rating
                FROM vwResults
                ORDER BY runnerid, Rating) as sq
          WHERE rank <= 3
          GROUP BY runnerid) as top3rating
        on (r.id = top3rating.runnerid);
END //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'r.id' in 'where clause' it seems not to see r that deep in to the query

Comment: Update the solution above worked however, I am unable to create a view due to the sub queries. I don't think its possible to do what I want to and create a view out of it.  Think I will look into creating a function to pull the ratings and just adding it to the table as rating.  I know nothing about functions though but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Put it in a stored procedure.  Answer has been updated with an example.

Comment: I would perfer a function just because I can put the function inline with my user query to pull the rating.  If I create a procedure then I have to call it seperate and unless I could query the procedure like a view this would cause me to have to rework alot of my code to implement.

Comment: Be careful with how you implement and use the scalar function; used in a select query it can be very slow (it will get executed for every row).  If you are only trying to retrieve one user's rank at a time, this should be fine.  If you need more users at a time, you could have the procedure insert the results into a temporary table and select them outside of the procedure.

Comment: I got it using a small chunk of your procedure code I was able to create the function that generated what I needed.

Comment: Looks like it is alittle slow but not so bad I was able to load 500 records in 8 seconds though the most I will need to load at once is 100 the rest will be single loads.

Comment: Looks like you where right the query in the database is not to bad was able to pull 100 records in around 1 second.  However when I move over to my site it dose alot of querys but still less then 100 but it was unable to load the view.  not sure what the deal is but I may not be able to use a function either

Comment: I found the problem using mysql_num_rows in my profile to generate rankings based on rating theres no way around this will not be able to use the function after 500 rows it gets to slow. My have to try and go with the procedure / temp table idea though it would require alot of additional code.  May just stick with my manual rating update script.

Comment: I think the procedure idea would be a much better approce if only I can get it implamented I will not have to change much code at all. just table names in a few queries.  I posted a sample above that I am trying to get to work.